# PSpice student edition, no VDC?

Tags: pspice

I downloaded PSpice 9.1 Student Edition from Electronics Lab (basically the first google result for "PSpice Student Edition"). I am trying to follow some basic circuit tutorials and I get the point where I am trying to add the part "VDC" to add a basic voltage supply....and it's not in my parts list!

I went to the "Add Library..." and added every library that was available, but still no luck.

What gives? How can I include a basic DC voltage source in my circuit?

Comment: Try VSRC voltage source

Comment: I find OrCAD sim a bit awkward. I use micro-cap - see this picture and notice the easy pick and place component symbol palette just under the "MODEL" Tab on the top line - note the battery symbol: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Screenshot_Micro-Cap_12.png. You can download the free student edition.

Comment: there's also free from TI \DesignSoft\Tina 9 - TI\SPICE and LTI's   LTspiceXVII

Comment: @Andyaka You can download Micro-Cap12 free http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm Spectrum Software is closed. Micro-Cap is now free.

Comment: @G36 that is a shocker. Downloading full version right now. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @G36 and yes it appears to work with the full libraries and facilities. Nice one.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes,know that.